# How to use CCRC to get old file versions?

Tags: java, api, clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

I'm trying to use CCRC API in order to get, for instance, all versions for a specific file and get some old file version.

I've tried to use CHILD_LIST, CHILD_MAP, tried to use CcFile.getVersion().getPredecessor() and then use CcFile.doReadProperties(...) but it seems that the location is remote and then is not possible to get the file using for example getClientPath().

I already saw that is possible to retrieve all versions for a specific file using CCRC plugin and select a specific version clicking in the version three.

Does anybody have some example how to retrieve this version without setting the config spec ?

tks
Kleber

Comment: What type of CCRC API do you use? any url for reference?

Answer (score 0):

The [CCRC CLI](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24021929) is not very complete in 7.X, and even the first 8.0.0.x.

**[rcleartool](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21598728)** is completed with the latest 8.x releases, and included a [`rcleartool get`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8m0r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_get.htm) which allows you to access any version you want.

See more details at "[How to use CCRC to get prievous file version?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18269319/6309)".